# How to validate jQuery UI Date Picker "From Date" to "To Date"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 fields "From date" and "To date". I am new in jQuery and I am learning it.

1. When selecting from date on jQuery UI Date Picker, all previous
   dates (before current date) to be un-selectable (greyed out).
2. When selecting to date, only dates starting from current date

   - 1 day to be selectable (cannot select same from date or date passed as to date)

**I am currently using this code:**

```
$( function() {
var dateFormat = "dd-mm-yy",
  from = $( "#from" )
    .datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3
    })
    .on( "change", function() {
      to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
    }),
  to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3
  })
  .on( "change", function() {
    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
  });

function getDate( element ) {
  var date;
  try {
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
  } catch( error ) {
    date = null;
  }

  return date;
}
});
```

**Note:** Date format should be "**dd-mm-yy**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grey out dates before current date, simply set minDate to current date in the datepicker configuration.

```
minDate: new Date()
```

You also should explicitly set the dateFormat option to be the same as the one you are using in $.datepicker.parseDate call.

If I understood your problem correctly, this fiddle should be about right (modified your code a bit)

http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/1846/